# Use data from one api call in another api call concurrently

Tags: javascript

How to use data as a result from api call as a response in another concurrently?

I've got this function

```
const foo = async() => {
  await firstCall()
  await secondCall()
}
```

calling `firstCall()` i want to get data and save them inside some variable and when this data is received use data as params inside secondCall()

Comment: Return that data from `firstCall` and pass it to `secondCall`?  What have you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a variable `data` inside your async function `foo` and assign it a value which is the value returned from calling the `firstCall` function:

```js
  const foo = async() => {
   const data = await firstCall()
   await secondCall(data)
}
```

For more info you can read documentations at [MDN - async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).